# someone help me to fix IOError?

Tags: python, csv

This is the function which make an attempt to update the content:

```
def write_csv(self, file_path, fields, rows):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fields)
        writer.writerow(dict(zip(fields, fields)))
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

The error which I'm getting is as follows:

```
C:\sample_data_set.csv
Initial Records : 19
Removed : 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python_project/amit_test.py", line 79, in <module>
v.main()
File "C:/Python_project/amit_test.py", line 73, in main
self.write_csv('output/{0}'.format(os.path.basename(file_path)), fields,      rows)
File "C:/Python_project/amit_test.py", line 41, in write_csv
with open(file_path, 'wb') as csvFile:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output/sample_data_set.csv'
```

I have checked that the path of sample_data_set.csv correct and does exist.

Complete code is available here https://gist.github.com/shashank136/f5557a1d0a42d1ae615a6e4c12b21ff7

Comment: try using full file path

Answer (score 0):

file_path

maybe

```
file_path = r"C:\Python_project\output\sample_data_set.csv"
```

you can try!

Comment: @Shashank Kumar: Hello I download the file from GitHub and I trying to see the error but I don't have the file-> sample_data_set.csv, so I cannot see any error when I execute it. Can you give me the file?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your file_path, notes that it doesn't automatically create the intermediate directories when you opening a file

```
import os

def write_csv(self, file_path, fields, rows):

    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_path), exist_ok=True)

    with open(file_path, 'wb') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=fields)
        writer.writerow(dict(zip(fields, fields)))
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the changes you suggested didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Same error or is it different and what is your Python version?